# SerializationException was unhandled: The input stream is not a valid binary format. The starting contents (in bytes) are

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization

really stuck, any help and/or comments would be greatly appreciated!

I've written a database program that needs to be able to load contents from a file into a list. So basically i'm trying to use serialization and deserialization for this. The area where the error occurs is in bold and is italicized:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class TheFile
    {
        //Version 1 serialiser, instance specific, so a bit of a pain

        public void SerializeObject(string filename, TheDocument document)
        {
            Stream stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Create);
            BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            bFormatter.Serialize(stream, document);
            stream.Close();
        }
        public TheDocument DeSerializeObject(string filename)
        {
            TheDocument document;
            Stream stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open);
            BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            ***document = (TheDocument)bFormatter.Deserialize(stream);***
            stream.Close();
            return document;
        }
    }
}
```

The error which i receive is as follows: The input stream is not a valid binary format. The starting contents (in bytes) are: 31-37-2F-30-39-2F-32-30-31-31-20-31-31-3A-30-36-3A ...

Comment: btw - does the error show in the file version? or only when talking to a database? if the latter... what is the code that writes/reads the BLOB? getting the BLOB handling wrong when talking to a database is very common...

Comment: That's "17/09/2011 11:06:".  Something is adding the current date and time to the file.  Have a look-see with Notepad first, check the *filename* argument with the debugger next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this reported somewhere else recently, and I was unable to find an explanation there *either*. The code as presented looks like it *should* be fine (although it would benefit greatly from a few `using` statements, but they won't break the success case since you are calling `.Close()`).

However! I would also warn that IMO `BinaryFormatter` is ***not*** a good choice for storage in a database, since that suggests it is desirable to read it back *in the future*. The fact that `BinaryFormatter` is type-dependent makes it very very brittle as you version your application. Any of: creating a new app-version, renaming/adding/removing a field, changing a property to an automatically implemented property, changing .NET version, changing platform, ... *could* make your data either unreadable, or readable only by adding a lot of custom binder code.

I *strongly* suggest that you consider using a contract-based serializer instead of `BinaryFormatter`; any of: `DataContractSerializer` (but not `NetDataContractSerializer`), `XmlSerializer`, `JavascriptSerializer`, JSON.Net. If you want binary for size and performance, then protocol buffers (with several C# implementations, including protobuf-net) is designed (by Google) to be version tolerant, small, and fast. Since that list is also cross-platform, it also means your data is safe if, say, you switch platform to Java, Mono, WinRT (the new windows 8 subsystem), PHP, or anything else. `BinaryFormatter` will *not* work on any of those.

Comment: Hey, Thanks so much for looking into it. It's so sad that i can't get this to work.

Comment: Also, thank you GREATLY for the advice on using a contract-based serializer!! I will definitely do this!

Comment: Emphasis on "could" make your data unreadable. I just tested adding/removing fields and bumping assembly version and BinaryFormatter didn't care (new fields were null, removed fields didn't cause an exception, nor did changing assembly version).

Answer (score 0):

Does this succeed?

```
var path = "...";
var doc = new TheDocument(...);

SerializeObject(path, doc);
var restored = DeserializedObject(path);

Assert.IsNotNull(restored); // NUnit check; use appropriate code
```

Too big for a comment