# Strange FormatExceptions when using BinaryFormatter

Tags: c#, serialization, formatexception

I have a TCP application set up so that the server and client communicate using serialized objects that have been serialized by BinaryFormatter and then encoded with Base64. Here is the code for both convert to string (for sending across stream) and convert to object (for receiving from stream).

```
    private string SerializeObject(object obj)
    {
        using(var memStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(memStream, obj);
            memStream.Flush();
            memStream.Position = 0;

            return Convert.ToBase64String(memStream.ToArray());
        }
    }

    private object DeserializeStream(string str)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var memStream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(str)))
            {
                var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                return (object)formatter.Deserialize(memStream);
            }
        }
        catch (SerializationException e) { OutputError(e); return null; }
        catch (DecoderFallbackException e1) { OutputError(e1); return null; }
        catch (FormatException) { return null; }
    }
```

When I receive data, I do it like so:

```
StreamReader r = new StreamReader(cli.GetStream());
string str = r.ReadLine(); 
if ((str == "") || (str == null)) 
{ 
    ShutdownClient(-2); 
}
else
{
    object o = DeserializeStream(str);
    if (o == null)
    { ResendLastPacket(); }
    else 
    { ParsePacket(o); }
}
```

EDIT: Here's the send method

```
        public void Send(Packet packData)
        {
            try
            {
                StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(clientObject.GetStream());
                w.WriteLine(SerializeData(packData));
                w.Flush();
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException) { }
            catch (IOException) { CloseObject(); }
        }
```

Where Packet is a custom object which HAS [Serializable].
clientObject is a TcpClient.

Now, when I start the client and server on the same machine, the program generally works fine. No errors whatsoever. But if I transfer the client application to a remote PC and use it from there, I mainly get FormatExceptions. Mostly with the error:

```
"The input stream is not a valid binary format. The starting contents (in bytes) are: 6D-2E-44-72-61-77-69-6E-67-2E-43-6F-6C-6F-72-0F-00 ..."
```

What am I doing wrong here? Or what can I use instead that will act as a more efficient alternative?

Comment: Maybe take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459435/serializationexception-was-unhandled-the-input-stream-is-not-a-valid-binary-for

Comment: @S.Spieker That unforunately doesn't help. I'm trying to accomplish network communication, that's why I'm using BinaryFormatter. But thank you for your reply.

Comment: You haven't shown what you're *doing* with the data. You could also add a diagnostic check to try deserializing the data you've serialized immediately, with no transmission involved.

Comment: @JonSkeet Well, I'm transmitting the data via TCP stream using that code above. I don't think it's a matter of that because the transmission doesn't throw any exceptions when I use both server and client on the same machine. The problems only start when I try it on another PC.

Comment: @Daaksin: Which code above? You've shown no code which *sends* data - only code which *receives* data. But again, I'd suggest you isolate the serialization part from the transmission part - see http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2014/01/20/diagnosing-issues-with-reversible-data-transformations.aspx

Comment: @JonSkeet I'll add the send method. I'm sorry.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you for your text. I'll be sure to read and apply it.

Comment: @JonSkeet Oh and I should probably mention; when running client in debug mode with VS2013, when I connect to a server on a remote PC, it works fine.

Comment: Add a logging library and dump the binary data on client and server.  But you're showing a pair of methods SerializeObject/DeserializeStream, whereas your send method is calling a method SerializeData that you're not showing.

Comment: @Joe Yes, I accidentally took the methods from both server and client. And for some reason, I gave them slightly seperate names, but it is the same thing. I will try your suggestion, thanks